# Using Pragma-s of SQLite in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I posted a question:

"My Projects has c++ dll in which a db is created in Sqllite with share deny = none. This dll will insert data into Db and I have a c# exe which must access the db and display it. Display needs to be done asynchronously. So is there any way while launching connection to sqlitedb I can lock the table or db. If possible, can anyone give me links or a sample of how it can be done? "

For this, I got a reply to use Pragma -s. Can anyone tell me how to implement PRagma-s of SQLlite in C#?

Comment: Why not ask there itself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286772/lock-a-sqlite-database-for-reading-from-c

Comment: @subbu: Only 25 minutes passed since you asked that question. Please grow patience.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pragmas can be set in your connection string

For eg: 
`String conString = "Data Source=filename;Version=3;PRAGMA locking_mode = NORMAL;"`

You can append more than one pragma to the connection string

Comment: I'm confused because this doesn't seem to work... data source=Test.db;version=3;PRAGMA RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS=1;"  Any thoughts as to why not?

Comment: I've had success with using pragma-s in connection string without the "PRAGMA" keyword, such as this: `"Data Source={0};Version=3;Synchronous=OFF;Journal Mode=WAL;"`

Comment: Synchronous=OFF;Journal Mode=WAL; did it thank you very much. i have more than 10x increase in speed now

Comment: For reference these are connection string parameters supported by `System.Data.SQLite`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteconnectionstringbuilder?view=msdata-sqlite-6.0.0